# Filling dropdownlist from DB

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm trying to move over to MVC from webforms, and to be honest, it's not going very well.

I need a `DropDownList` populated with values from my database, and I'm having a hard time understanding how to do this.
I'm thinking, that I need to create a model,using entity framework, and refer my `DropDownList` to that? But how do I point it to that model?
Also, if I make a model, from a database table, how do I adjust the select command, so I only get certain values, and not the entire table?

I know this is kind of a broad question, and I have no examples listed, but I've had a really hard time, finding information I could understand, with regards to my issue.

Comment: at what point are you stuck are you creating a list as part of the model or just a list

Comment: I'm pretty much stuck, before I even start. I have no idea how to begin. I'm assuming the correct way, is to make a model, and somehow use that.

Comment: are you using code first or you already have db

Comment: I have the DB already. I have a table with LOV values, but I need to use only the ones, with a special ListName.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start from this this should get you the project created if you have not done so so you can have the model ready

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg685489

in order to create a dropdownlist here is an example

```
ViewBag.dropdownlist = new SelectList(db.tablename, "Valuefiled", "NameGField");
```

where Valuefiled=name of a column in your database that you want to use for values

"NameGField"=name of a column in your database that you want to use for names

getting drop down list to view

```
@Html.DropDownList("dropdownlist")
```

Comment: How do I filter this then? I want to only select the entries, where the column ListNAme is a certain value.

Comment: Fix it by adding a ToList().Where() to the db.tablename in the selectlist constructor.

Answer (score 1):

How About this

Your ViewModel

```
   public class CategoryViewModel
   {
    public Category Category { get; set; }   
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CategoryTitles { get; set; }   
   }
```

Your Controller

```
 public ActionResult Create()
    {
       var categoryviewmodel = new CategoryViewModel();              
       categoryviewmodel.Category = new Category();
       var list = categoryRepository.AllCategoryTitles().ToList().Select(t => new SelectListItem
          {
                Text = t.CategoryName,
                Value = t.CategoryID.ToString()
          })
          .ToList();           
          list.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Value = "0", Text = "Please Selext" });          

        categoryviewmodel.CategoryTitles = list;
        return View(categoryviewmodel);
    }
```

Your Repository

```
    public IQueryable<Category> AllCategoryTitles()
    {       
        var query = context.Categories.Where(m => m.ParentCategoryID == null && m.IsActive==true);
        return query;
    }
```

Your View

```
  @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.CategoryParentID, Model.CategoryTitles)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a viewModel. Here is an example solution with some assumptions. Refer to the dropdownlist (here in the dropdown I am listing departments of type "InBound"

Employee Model

```
public class EmployeeModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int DeptId { get; set; }
}
```

Department Model

```
public class DepartmentModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel (to be passed into the view)

```
public class EmployeeViewModel
{
    public EmployeeModel Employee { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<DepartmentModel> Departments { get; set; }
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        EmployeeViewModel vm = new EmployeeViewModel();

        //This is hardcoded. However you will write your own method to pull the department details with filtering
        List<DepartmentModel> departments = new List<DepartmentModel>() { new DepartmentModel { Id = 1, Name = "Accounts", Type = "InBound" }, new DepartmentModel { Id = 2, Name = "Finance", Type = "OutBound" }, new DepartmentModel { Id = 3, Name = "HR", Type = "InBound" } };
        vm.Departments = departments.Where(d => d.Type == "InBound"); 

        return View(vm);
    }
```

View

```
    @model Test1.ViewModels.EmployeeViewModel
    @{
          ViewBag.Title = "Index";
     }

     <h2>Index</h2>
     @using (Html.BeginForm())
     {
         @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Employee.Id);
      <table>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.FirstName)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employee.FirstName)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Employee.LastName)</td>
            <td>@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Employee.LastName)</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>@Html.Label("Department")</td>
            <td>@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Employee.DeptId, new SelectList(Model.Departments, "Id", "Name"))</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
}
```